# Google AdSense Ad placement above fold in-article

Tags: google-adsense, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to AdSense. I want to place an ad on most of the pages of my website, which are articles (mostly text).

For mobile devices, I'd like the ad to appear below the headline and below some of the article text, but at least partially visible above the bottom of the screen ("above the fold"). Is there a way to do this within AdSense? If so, how can it be done? If not, is there a relatively simple way to do it programmatically? My site is Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put ads in the page where you want them in Google AdSense.   For a long time, that was the only way to use it.  Now Google is pushing "auto ads" that place the ads on the page for you.   You can still place ads yourself, but you need to disable auto ads across the board in your account settings.

You need to create a "placement" in Google AdSense for the ad.  Then put the JavaScript snippet for that ad into your page where you want the ad to appear.  Google has full instructions here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/160534?hl=en